# What does mogrify do when no arguments are specified?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, mogrify

I was receiving an iCCP error with some png images. I ran them through mogrify as follows

```
$ mogrify borked_image.png
```

While this resolved my issue (I assume by removing/correcting bad iCCP data), I want to know exactly what exactly is happening in order to mitigate risk to my project.

Comment: It will load your image into memory and re-encode and write back to disk under the original filename - preserving pretty much everything.

Comment: Like Mark said, except if it detects bad ancillary chunks in the input file (like known incorrect iCCP profiles) it will remove them.  The file size might change due to different optimization of the compression.